# Parsing JSON array of strings in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC5 project that uses this jQuery AJAX call

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ClientDetails2/" + document.getElementById('clientid').value,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (json) {
        $('#FirstName').text(json['Client'].FirstName);

        $.each(json['Cases'],         <-----
            function(value) {         <-----
                console.log(value);   <-----
            });                       <-----
    });
```

to return this JSON:

```
{
    Client: {
        Id: 1,
        LastName: "Clark",
        FirstName: "Keith",
        PrimaryPhone: "(555) 555-1212",
        Email: "myemail@yahoo.com"
    },
    Cases: [
        "Case1",
        "Case2",
        "Case3"
    ]
}
```

The `$('#FirstName').text(json['Client'].FirstName);` works fine and updates the DOM correctly.

Where I am getting hung up is in iterating thru `Cases`.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Keith Clark

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/15s0qL0x/)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I need to be able to iterate using the `.each` option as I will never know how many items are in that array

Comment: check this updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/15s0qL0x/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`$.each()` takes two parameters index and value

```js
var json  = {
    Client: {
        Id: 1,
        LastName: "Clark",
        FirstName: "Keith",
        PrimaryPhone: "(555) 555-1212",
        Email: "myemail@yahoo.com"
    },
    Cases: [
        "Case1",
        "Case2",
        "Case3"
    ]
};
         
 $.each(json['Cases'], function(index, value) {        
       console.log(index +' -> '+value);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply...I had the epiphany as you were typing your reply

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue.  Even though there is no actual `key:value` paring in the array, there is still an implied index that has to be accounted for in the function call.  I modified my code to this:

```
    $.each(json['Cases'],         
        function(index,value) {         
            console.log(value);   
        });
```

and all works as expected now.